# CSS Sprites not showing up on Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery to dynamically load CSS Sprites on a couple of `div` elements (that are within a wrapping `div`). Most of the time this works fine. However, one user informed me now that the sprites are simply not showing up. Unfortunately it's hard to create a jsFiddle for it as this mostly does not happen.

Since it is an app built with PhoneGap Build, a webkit browser is used to display the app. Are there any known issues regarding sprites and Android/Webkit browsers that could cause this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Sure I can show some code, for simplicity I will only use one image-`div` (that gets a sprite)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="image0"></div>
</div>
```

The markup is

```
#wrapper div[id^="image"] {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

(shouldn't do much) and the sprite gets initialized with (I edited out the loop condition)

```
for (<i>) {
    $('#image' + i).css('background-image', 'url(img/myimage.png)')
           .css('background-size', (2*someVar) + 'px')
           .css('background-position', '0 -' + (2*i*someVar) + 'px');
}
```

Another piece of code sizes the div correctly. Like I said: It works fine everywhere I test it, but one user told me he's having problems.

Comment: Is it working on Chrome or Safari on PC or Mac?

Comment: Working fine on PC both in Firefox and Chrome for me.

Comment: That's weird! `:O` Can you post some code?

Comment: I will edit it into the question!

Comment: Woah, you are loading this via JavaScript? Fine, one **stupid** question. Did you include jQuery, not jQM? :P

Comment: Of course ;) If I didn't, it'd work nowhere. Plus the whole app wouldn't work. ;) By the way: I encountered the same issue sometimes (but rarely), but clicking on the picture (they have ontouch-events) solved it then. I feel like it might be connected, but I don't really know what causes it.

Comment: Let us wait for others' answers. :)

Comment: Yeah. I now explicitly asked him to check if clicking on any of the images solves it for him, too. But in any case I'd like to know what causes it and how to solve it.

Comment: Do you know what version of android your user has? This may be significant... and also what device they're using.

Comment: He's using a Sony-Ericsson Xperia X10 mini pro. I'm not sure about the exact OS version, but I wouldn't think that it's "too new". Still, I feel like CSS Sprites are basic enough to assume it should be working?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely the sprite being too big for a mobile browser to use. Either by file-size or by resolution. Try splitting the sprite in two files and see if it helps.

I've had a similiar problem with sprites not showing up on iOS because they were too big.

Comment: Woah – I'm so sorry, I didn't see your answer. I actually know more now. The sprite is being displayed, but for some reason it isn't sized correctly (it gets repeated way too often inside the container). I highly doubt that it's a resolution issue as this user's resolution is really low and I load a sprite set according to the resolution, so the image used on his phone is really small. I don't have any feedback yet if it's working in the latest version, so let's wait and see.

Comment: In my company we've been like crazy trying to find out what was causing the sprite to be transparent everywhere and this answer was just right! we added a few new images to the sprite, then it stopped showing any of them

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a few days ago (everything was looking fine on IOS but not on Android). So after some attempts I found that if you just pass `background-repeat: no-repeat;` attribute (hopefully) you will solve the problem.